# What type of nutrients can be applied foliarly?

Tags: plant-physiology

I am interested in what type of nutrients can you spray on plants? Which ones do get used by a plant and which ones make no difference.

By nutrients I mean general fertilisers N,P,K and also micro elements.

Comment: Stack exchange has a beta site on [Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) and *'general care and **feeding** of plants'* is on-topic there. I think this is better suited there as the question is framed along the line of Gardening and not Biology.